# How to make Chrome open bookmarks and URLs in new tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-extensions

I principally use Firefox both at home and at work, but on occasion I use Chrome.  I have Firefox working the way I like it by having it open bookmarks in a new tab when left clicked, as well, URLs open in new tabs.  Although having URLs open in a new tab can be annoying if I type a bad URL, I still prefer it, but that's neither here nor there.

I would like to replicate this behaviour in Chrome, and can't seem to find anything relavent in the settings.  Is there any way of doing this without an extension?  If not, can you point me towards an appropriate extension (I've already done a search and can't find what I'm looking for)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default Chrome acts like the default Firefox concerning tabs...

The behaviour of Tabs Mix Plus that you describe is available in [ChromePlus](http://www.chromeplus.org/). ;-)

(One Caveat about Chromeplus is that they do not update their core Chrome engine version as soon as it puts one out.  It is often at least one, sometimes two version numbers behind Chrome)

Comment: Thank you! One quick question though: Does ChromePlus support rocker gestures?  Right click and drag is good enough, but I prefer the rocker gestures for navigation.

Comment: See http://www.chromeplugins.org/google/chrome-plugins/new-chrome-mouse-gestures-plugin-rocker-support-7577.html

Comment: @TomWijsman Your link must have gone dead...

Comment: @KonradViltersten From what I can tell, they've renamed to **CoolNovo**; but given that it times out on me, I'm not sure whether that website is up.

Comment: I get timeout too. Not trusting plugins that behave this way, hehe. Any other suggestion on the TabMix-equivalent for Chrome? I'm **this** (showing tiney-whiney distance with my fingers) close to switching from FF to Cr right now...

Answer (score 3):

Hold down the CTRL key when you click on a link/bookmark, this will open it into a new tab.

Comment: NO! I don't want to hold down ctrl, middle click, right click and select from a menu, or anything like that.  I just want to be able to left click because I have been doing that and will continue to do that whenever I use Firefox.

Comment: AFAIK, this opens the page in a new *tab*, not a new window on all major browsers.

Comment: @Ross yes, I said "new window" when I should have actually said "new tab", will edit the original answer.

Comment: ALT-Enter, not CTRL-Enter. And for the record, i wish TabMix Plus for Firefox were available for Chrome because it lets you set opening links, bookmarks, etc. in a new tab/window.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [this extension.](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/akochnkdhdcmglamkeoeleclfhjdolkf?hl=en)

Comment: NO! Opening links in a webpage isn't the problem because I just use the same action as I do in firefox: middle click if I want it in a new tab, left click if I don't.

Comment: OK, how about dragging the bookmark to the tab at the top?  It will open in a new tab.

Comment: "I would like to replicate this behaviour in Chrome"
All I do is left click a bookmark and it opens in a new tab.  Doing anything different in Chrome introduces cognitive dissonance.  I'd rather not have to relearn how to do something for the rare occasions I use Chrome.

Comment: Then you won't be able to do it with Chrome.  There are currently no addons for this.  There are several threads on the google forums about it and no resolutions besides what has been offered to you here.

Answer (score 2):

The [Chrome Toolbox extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-toolbox-by-google/fjccknnhdnkbanjilpjddjhmkghmachn) adds several config options to Chrome, i.e. to open a new tab when you manually enter an URL into the address bar, or double clicking a tab to close it.

However, this works only on Windows so far, for some mysterious reason the extension [lacks those features in Mac OS](https://code.google.com/p/chrome-toolbox/issues/detail?can=2&start=100&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=141). So I'm still looking for way to do the same on my MacBook.

---

#### Edit:

I have now found a [custom extension](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/qtCjFJALdFA/aRXifdKQKgEJ) which will provide the desired functionality, although it doesn't seem to work properly all of the time.
You'll also have to install the extension manually, i.e. downloading it and then dragging it into your Extension page.
Note that this extension is totally unsupported and you'll have to use it on your own risk.

Comment: It doesn't do bookmarks, but URLs are the big thing.  Thanks!

Comment: For bookmarks, you can try the [Bookmarks Menu](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmarks-menu/ffmdedmghpoipeldijkdlcckdpempkdi) extension.  
It'll add a new '_favorite icon_' next to your address bar which will display your bookmarks onclick. In the options you can then define to open those bookmarks in a new tab.  

I still haven't found a proper way for the URL issue on the MacBook. Or Rocker gestures without having JavaScript enabled for all pages.

Comment: I have an extension for mouse gestures that does rocker gestures already, although I don't know if it requires JavaScript.  I know I shouldn't be doing this, but I leave JavaScript on, except for what's blocked by AdBlock.

Comment: Yeah, I tried various extensions, but they all require JavaScript to be allowed for the page (I use ScriptSafe to emulate Firefox' NoScript).  The same is true for the AutoScroll extension, which brings back the middle click scroll lock that doesn't seem to exist on Mac/Linux (wtf?).

Comment: I've found a [custom extension](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/qtCjFJALdFA/aRXifdKQKgEJ) which seems to work most of the time.
It opens a new tab and copies the URL of the address you've entered into that new tab, then it will perform a history.back() on the original tab. This means that you'll lose all "forward history" on your original tab.
Sometimes the extension seems to refuse to work alltogether, I haven't found a real pattern behind this yet. You'll also have to install the extension manually, i.e. by downloading the file and dragging it into the Extension page.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old but I'll post my solution regardless.

I have created a chrome extension that changes all existing bookmarks and also newly created ones to open on a left click. It's already saved me quite a few headaches.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-bookmarks/haandfikjmhahlpkhapifhkanmdaakop

I understand that the favicons are now default, but I have not found a fix for this yet. Chrome makes that part a little difficult. I hope this extension helps anyone and everyone. Please let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: Good start.  Do you think you can get the favicons fixed?  I just have the icon for most of my bookmarks.

Comment: I've tried a few solutions, but none of them have worked.  There's incredibly poor documentation about how to work with chrome's bookmarks, so that makes things very difficult.  I'll definitely keep working on it, though.

Answer (score 2):

I've just included this feature as part of my personal bookmark bar extension. With [these files](https://gist.github.com/Ursi/03893a3d017e7104fabed36e856c7ddf) you can create an extension that does just what you want. Unfortunately it does a little bit more than that as well. Because of how it works, any time you navigate to a URL that corresponds to one of your bookmark bar bookmarks, it will be opened in a new tab.

It works by going through all the bookmarks in your bookmarks bar (and is set to do this every time your bookmarks bar changes) and any time you navigate to one of these, it catches the request and redirects it to https://google.com/gen_204, which does absolutely nothing (you can click on it right now and see). This is the only way I could find to essentially stop a navigation without any unwanted side effects using the current tools in the Chrome API. After stopping the original bookmark click from doing anything, it opens up a new tab with the bookmark you clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think downloading chromePlus is a good idea, as pointed by Tom, since we still want to use Chrome. I did a search for "tabMixPlus" for Firefox in Chrome extensions but no luck. So here is my workaround:

So I used Drag and Go so that I could use mouse to drag the links and open it in a new tab (either background or foreground), and I still type the links in address bar, instead hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open in new tabs. I know it is one extra key that I have to push, but so far I lived with it until someone developed an extension for that.

Answer (score -1):

Another easy way is to use the scroll wheel of the mouse. Click on the link with the scroll wheel and that will open the link in a new tab.

Answer (score -1):

I have been looking for a solution for ages.
Came across this replacement bookmark extension for chrome.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmarks-menu/ffmdedmghpoipeldijkdlcckdpempkdi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

It is great. UI setting to open bookmarks in new tab. Also all has aesthetic options.

Comment: Please remove the rants from your answer.